# Delete not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I'm confused why my delete is not working.
My `route`

```
Route::get('/delete-works/{id}/', [
'uses' => 'WorksController@getDeleteWorks',
'as' => 'Works.delete',
'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

My `controller`

```
public function getDeleteWorks(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $class_id  = $request->get('class_id');

        $works = assainments::where('id', $id)->first();

        $works->delete();

        Flash::success('Successfuly deleted!');
        return redirect(route('works',['class_id'=>$class_id]));

    }
```

My `view link`

```
<a href="{{ route('Works.delete', ['class_id'=>$class_id,'id' => $works->id]) }}" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Now it's show blank white page. Not show any `error`.

Comment: Did you tried to debug your route? Try to dd your $request for example.

Comment: Are you sure `assainments` is not supposed to be `Assainments` ? Also, where is the `class_id` supposed to be delivered? The route string does not contain a `class_id` parameter.

Comment: I guess my route is problem but i can't found it.

Comment: Yes i'm sure assainments is not supposed to Assainments. My works page is open by class id. But my others delete option i create this proses. But why it's not working?

Comment: If it shows a blank page it's a hint that you do not reach the redirect. You can simply call dd(...) on the different objects and see where it fails.